# Showing values on barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn, catplot

The following code generates a pdf file that is fed by a looping barplot over a data frame. My goal is to annotate values over the bars. I have already tried various times to monitor the values but failed. May I get any help on this? Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

d = {'index': ['index1', 'index1', 'index2', 'index2'], 'group': ['gr1', 'gr1','gr2','gr2'],
targetscore':[15,15,10,10], 'exam':['old','new','old','new'], 'score':[5,6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
pp = PdfPages('mypath/extraction.pdf')
for i in range(len(df['group'])):
subdf = df[df['group'] == df.iloc[i,1]]
sns.catplot(y = 'score', x = 'group', data = subdf, hue = 'exam', kind = 'bar', 
        row = 'index', col = 'exam', col_order = ['old', 'new'], height = 3, aspect = 2)
plt.show
pp.savefig(plt.gcf())
pp.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)

Comment: I have gone through a several explanations mainly regarding FacetGrids but at the end I did not manage to implement a simple display on the bar chart.